# Add Dayname to Date Column in Pivot SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a dayname before the Date '01.08.2022, 02.08.2022 etc.'
My table looks like this:

| First Name | Last Name | 01.08.2022 | 02.08.2022 | 03.08.2022 | 04.08.2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Name | -------- | -------------- | -------- | -------------- |
| Name | Name | -------- | -------------- | -------- | -------------- |
| Name | Name | -------- | -------------- | -------- | -------------- |

I want it to look like this:

| First Name | Last Name | Mo. 01.08.2022 | Tue. 02.08.2022 | Wed. 03.08.2022 | Thu. 04.08.2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Name | -------- | --------- | -------- | ------------- |
| Name | Name | -------- | --------- | -------- | -------------- |
| Name | Name | -------- | --------- | -------- | -------------- |

My Code is :

```
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';



SELECT @columns = STUFF((SELECT ',' +  QUOTENAME(Datum) as Datum from

            (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar,Datum,104) as Datum
            FROM  TABLE1
            Where Datum > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
            and Datum < DATEADD(day, +13, GETDATE())

            )sub

            ORDER BY Datum

        
            
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')



SET @sql ='
SELECT * FROM   
(
    select DISTINCT Vorname, Nachname, Bezeichnung, Datum from TABLE1 a
left join TABLE2 b
    ON a.Mitarbeiter_ID = b.Mitarbeiter_ID

    WHERE a.Bezeichnung is not null
    and a.Bezeichnung <> ''''

    and Datum > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
    and Datum < DATEADD(day, +13, GETDATE())
    
) t 

PIVOT(
    MAX(Bezeichnung)
    FOR Datum IN ('+ @columns +')

) AS pivot_table;';


EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Any suggestions how to combine this date format with dayname?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have? `select @@version`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5014356) - 15.0.2095.3 (X64)

Comment: Does `Datum` have a time component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add an alias to the column names. It's easier to do this if you do a manual pivot using `MAX(CASE WHEN`, because then you only need one `@columns` variable, whereas with `PIVOT` you need to split it up by actual values and aliases.

You are using SQL Server 2019, so you can use the newer `STRING_AGG` which is much easier.

```
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @columns = STRING_AGG(
    CONCAT(
      '  MAX(CASE WHEN Datum = ',
      QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(20), Datum, 112), ''''),
      ' THEN Bezeichnung END) AS ',
      QUOTENAME(LEFT(DATENAME(weekday, Datum), 3) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), Datum, 112))
    )
  , ',
' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Datum)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Datum
    FROM  TABLE1
    Where Datum > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
      and Datum < DATEADD(day, +13, GETDATE())
) sub;

SET @sql ='
SELECT
  t.Vorname,
  t.Nachname, 
' + @columns + '
FROM   
(
    select DISTINCT Vorname, Nachname, Bezeichnung, Datum
    from TABLE1 a
    left join TABLE2 b ON a.Mitarbeiter_ID = b.Mitarbeiter_ID

    WHERE a.Bezeichnung is not null
      and a.Bezeichnung <> ''''

      and Datum > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
      and Datum < DATEADD(day, +13, GETDATE())
) t
GROUP BY
  t.Vorname,
  t.Nachname;
';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: that seems to work with the dates, but im only getting 1 row without names.

Comment: Sorry missed off the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` columns